# ES6 arrow notation with Jquery filter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm filtering a Jquery collection like so:

```
$('li').filter(function(i, v) {
  if($(v).is('.selected')) {return v;}
})
```

Is there any way to shorten this to an arrow notation? Like the following, which does not work:

```
$('li').filter(x => $(x).is('.selected));
```

Comment: Try using the second parameter `(i, x) => $(x).is('.selected)`

Comment: @HereticMonkey This seems to be confusion about using multiple parameters with arrow notation, that question does not have anything to do with multiple parameters

Comment: @GammaGames Yep, and this is about jQuery's `filter`, not Array's `filter`. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parameters are still required. The first is the index, and the second is the element:

```js
$('li').filter((index, el) => $(el).is('.selected'));
```